# How can I configure WSO2 to automatically replace API urls?

Tags: uri, sequence, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API running on `http://my_internal_api.com`, and I'm exposing it with WSO2, on `https://mywso2:8280/my_api`.

Everything works just fine, but the REST API is giving off url attributes in json that are formatted for the original server url.

Example:
When retrieving contact info, I get a JSON object:

```
[{contact_id: 1, url: contact_url}, {}]
```

This `contact_url` is in the form: `http://my_internal_api.com/contacts/1`

It should be: `https://mywso2:8280/my_api/contacts/1`

Is there a way to solve this? I'm guessing a squence should be used, but I don't know if this is the right approach or I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a header mediator to add a X-Forwarded-Host header, like this:

```
<sequence name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <header name="X-Forwarded-Host"
          scope="transport"
          expression="get-property('transport','Host')"/>
    <header name="X-Forwarded-Proto" scope="transport" value="https"/>
</sequence>
```

This way, most APIs will be able to correctly resolve the host

Answer (score 0):

You can add an out sequence using mediation extension[1].There find all occurrence of "my_internal_api.com" and replace by "mywso2:8280".For replacing you string in the payload you can use the script mediator.

```
<script language="js">
var payload = mc.getPayloadXML().toString();
<property name="PAYLOAD" value="payload"/>
var changedPayload = payload.replace(/http:\/\/my_internal_api.com/, mc.getProperty('apiURL'));
var xml = new XML(newPayLoad);
mc.setPayloadXML(xml);</script>
```

1.https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

Comment: Hey Robin I'm having a little trouble with your code. My original response is in JSON , but getPayloadJSON returns nothing and getPayloadXML seems to return an empty element. Do you have any working example?